# Is it possible to vectorize the calculation of the distance from a source to an array of targets in a pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I currently have a pandas DataFrame set up like this:

```
ID, Source Coord, Target Coords

1, (35, -75), [(30, -72), (31, -71), ...]
2, (34, -74), [(50, -50), (45,-45), ...]
```

The source and target coordinates are latitude and longitudes. I have a vectorized function to calculate the distance from a source to some target nodes:

```
from numba import njit
@njit
def haversine_nb(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = np.radians(lon1), np.radians(lat1), np.radians(lon2), np.radians(lat2)
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = np.sin(dlat/2.0)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2.0)**2
    return 3958.7613 * 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))

def calculate_distance(source_loc, target_locs):
    tlat = np.array([t[0] for t in target_locs])
    tlon = np.array([t[1] for t in target_lcos])
    slat = np.full(tlat.shape, source_loc[0])
    slon = np.full(tlon.shape, source_loc[1])
    arr = haversine_nb(slat, slon, tlat,tlon)
```

I want to create another column in the DataFrame that holds the list of distances from the source to the target coordinates for each ID. Something like this:

```
ID, Source Coord, Target Coords, Distances(mi)

1, (35, -75), [(30, -72), (31, -71), ...], [5,1, ...]
2, (34, -74), [(50, -50), (45,-45), ...], [10, 2,...]
```

I know I can use the `.apply` function on the Dataframe, but it's very slow since the DataFrame is large.I was wondering if anyone knows if there is a way generate this new column using vectorization.

Comment: Does the `Target Coords` column consist of same size arrays/lists?

Comment: Put this in tidy notation, such that you have repeated source coordinates mapping each to one target coordinate (a many-to-one). Then vectorise over _those_columns.

Comment: @QuangHoang No, the Target Coords columns can have differing sizes.

Comment: @ifly6 Maybe that would work, but how would I be able to output an array of distances and append that as a column on the dataframe?

Comment: You don't. Keep the data in tidy format. If you really do need it in a less accessible format, then you can collapse it with a groupby and mapping back to lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expand to tidy format with a many-to-one mapping from sources to targets:

```
1, (35, -75), [(30, -72), (31, -71), ...]
```

Thus,

```
ID   Source     Target
1    (35, -75)  (30, -72)
1    (35, -75)  (31, -71)
1    (35, -75)  ...
```

Then just get distances from your vectorised columns between source and target. If you want it back in the ID-centric form, collapse it back into lists.

---

@ifly6, appologies for editing your post but it seemed the most efficient and appropriate way to get this information across.  Please edit as you see fit.

```
df_ = df.explode('Target Coords')

lat1, lon1 = map(np.array, zip(*df_['Source Coord']))
lat2, lon2 = map(np.array, zip(*df_['Target Coords']))

haversine_nb(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
```

Comment: I think this would work. Thank you for the suggestion. My only qualm would be it would take up a lot of memory, right?

Comment: How large is your dataset?